# WSL broken after uninstalling snapd

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

when I type:

```bsh
sudo apt install zsh
```

```
>Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apparmor file liblzo2-2 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmpdec2 libpython3-stdlib libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib mime-support python3 python3-minimal python3.7
  python3.7-minimal squashfs-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  zsh-common
Suggested packages:
  zsh-doc

E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success

E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

It fails every time I want to install a package so I'm stuck.
Maybe I should reinstall everything.

I've uninstalled `snapd` and the problem came up. I'm using a debian app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually remove the erroneous apt hook like this:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
```

(Take a backup first.)

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171273/uninstalled-snapd-from-windows-10-wsl-now-cant-install-anything)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.